# What is a k-wise intersection?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I am having a hard time visualizing and conceptualizing what a k-wise intersection is.

I am guessing 3-wise intersection for 3 sets: $S_1,S_2,S_3$ would be $(S_1 {\cap}S_2{\cap}S_3)$ and 2-wise intersection for 2 sets $(S_1{\cap}S_2) + (S_2{\cap}S_3) + (S_2{\cap}S_3)$ and so on.

But if we have more sets, say if we have 10 sets, how can I conceptualize it in my head?

Would the number of k-wise intersection just be representing $\binom{n}{k}$ where n is the number of sets and k is the k-wise intersection?

Is this correct way to think about k-wise intersection?

Comment: If I understand what you mean, you are correct.  There are ${n\choose k}$ $k-$wise intersections of $n$ sets.  By the way, when $k=2,$ it is usual to say "pairwise".

Comment: Perhaps this is a term you saw used somewhere?  If so, it would improve your Question to cite this source.  Otherwise it seems you introduce the term only to ask Readers to tell you what you mean by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything which looks like
$$
S_{i_1}\cap S_{i_2}\cap \dots \cap S_{i_k}
$$
is a $k$-wise intersection. If you have $n$ sets $S_1,S_2,\dots,S_n$, then the number of possible $k$-wise intersections of these sets is indeed $\binom{n}k$. Every size $k$ subset $A=\{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k\}$ of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ corresponds to exactly one $k$-wise intersection, namely the one above.

When using the Principle of Inclusion Exclusion, you will have to sum over all possible $k$-wise intersections, for each $k$. This summation is either written as
$$
\sum_{|A|=k}N({\textstyle\bigcap_{i\in A}}S_i) \hspace{1cm}\text{or}\hspace{1cm}\sum_{1\le i_1<i_2<\dots<i_k\le n}N(S_{i_1}\cap S_{i_2}\cap \dots \cap S_{i_k})
$$